# Can't use Geocoder class in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I have such trouble: I want to use ajax request to get user location, so I created action in my controller and rendering the result of Geocoder function in json. Here is code:

```
  def find_location
   location = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:location])
   render :json => (location)
  end
```

Locally it works great, on heroku it works too, but when I added this code to another project - it shows me this error

```
   NameError in ConnectionsController#find_location

   uninitialized constant ConnectionsController::Geocoder
```

It is strange, because **this is working in console:**

```
      Geocoder.coordinates "Ukraine"
       => [48.379433, 31.16558]
```

I tried to include Geocoder::Model, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Did you add geocoder gem to Gemfile of that another project?

Comment: Of course) Bundle show gemcoder shows me gemcoder

Comment: Typo) Geocoder of course. I can use it in my rails console, so it DO exists in my gemfile.

Comment: Does `location = ::Geocoder.coordinates(params[:location])` works instead of current `location = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:location])`?

Comment: When I put your first variant in my controller - I got error `uninitialized constant Geocoder`. In localhost I used - second variant.

Comment: In rails console - both your variant are working.

Comment: @Hck, maybe somehow it can't find module ? How can I get module location ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/239) you have to restart the whole production machine, not only your apache or nginx.

I actually had to open an issue because it doesn't work for me.
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/501

Answer (score 1):

make sure your `geocoder gem` is not grouped inside `:development`, or `:test` inside the `Gemfile`

it should be outside the groups so that I could accessed in all the environments

Ex:

```
#Gemfile

group :development, :test do
  #your gems
end 

gem 'geocoder'
```

Comment: it is out of groups and after mongoid gem/

Comment: if it is working on dev and not in prod, then it must me a loading issue. have u done a bundle install in your production environment as well ?

Comment: Yes, a run bundle install a few times. I saw this issue - https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/259 - should I restart server after making changes in application.rb file ? (added require 'geocoder/models/mongoid')

Comment: yes, in production mode, after u do any change you have to restart the server by doing, touch tmp/restart.txt

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Docker for your backend code by any chance?

If you do so, then after you installed any gem, you need to stop the Rails container, build (or pull down from dockerhub if you use dockerhub) the new image, and start your containers again.

All is well